# Finding the speed of the faster of two machines.

Tags: contest-math, solution-verification

This is a question from a maths contest and is as follows:

> Two machines move at constant speeds around a circle of circumference $600$ cm, starting together from the same point. If they travel in the same direction then they next meet after $20$ seconds, but if they travel in opposite directions then they next meet after $5$ seconds. At what speed, in centimetres per second, is the faster one travelling ?
>
> (A) $ 60 \quad\quad$ (B) $65 \quad\quad$ (C) $70 \quad\quad$ (D) $75 \quad\quad$ (E) $85 \quad\quad$

---

I did the following:
Let the machines be $A$ and $B$ with respective speeds $\nu_A$ and $\nu_B$ and considering the relative velocity of $B$ w.r.t. $A$.

For the case where they travel in the same direction:

$$\begin{align}
(\nu_A-\nu_B)\cdot 20=600\\
\therefore (\nu_A-\nu_B)=30 \tag{*}
\end{align}$$

For the case where they travel in opposite directions:

$$\begin{align}
(\nu_A+\nu_B)\cdot 5=600\\
\therefore (\nu_A+\nu_B)=120 \tag{†}
\end{align}$$

Hence ,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\dagger\right)-\left(*\right)}{2}=\nu_B=45\\
\\
\frac{\left(*\right)+\left(\dagger\right)}{2}=\nu_A=75\\
\end{align}$$

So, answer is $\; \mathbf{(D)}$

---

**Question**: Is what I've done right?

**Bonus question**: Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, what you did is right. A better way to do it may be to omit the calculation of $\nu_B$, since we're not interested in that.

Comment: In ultiple choice questions, sometimes "gaming" is more efficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer Better make sure, especially in exam-like situations where we are even inclined to check easy calculations on a calculator :). AndréNicolas: What do you mean by 'gaming'?